# Is such a function of class $C^1$

Tags: analysis

Let $X$ be a real Banach space and $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow X$ be continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, of class $C^1$ on $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ and there is a limit $$g=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f'(x).$$ Is then $f$ of class $C^1$ on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Have you tried the case when $X$ is $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes, in this case equality  $f'(0)=lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f'(x)$  follows from de L'Hospital rule, continuity of $f$  and definition of derivative.

Comment: Then everything you need still holds in the case of real Banach spaces I guess.

Comment: It may be more subtle than this. De l'Hospital's theorem is based on some mean value theorem, which is not expected to hold for vector-valued functions. I guess that a proof should follow a different path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rudin in his "Principles of mathematical analysis" proves the following form of the mean value theorem (Theorem 5.20 in my edition):

**Theorem 5.20**. Suppose $f$ is a continuous mapping of $[a,b]$ into ${\mathbb R}^k$ and $f$ is differentiable on $\ ]a,b[\ $. Then there is an $x\in\ ]a,b[\ $ such that $$|f(b)-f(a)|\leq(b-a)|f'(x)|\ .$$

I think the proof carries over from ${\mathbb R}^k$ to any Banach space $X$. Using this theorem we can argue as follows:

After replacing $f$ with $x\mapsto f(x)- x g$ we may assume $g=0\in X$. Let an $\epsilon>0$ be given. Then there is a $\delta>0$ such that 
$$|f'(x)|<\epsilon\qquad\forall x\in\dot U_\delta(0)\ .$$
Consider an arbitrary $t\in\dot U_\delta(0)$. By the above theorem there is a $\tau\in\ ]0,t[\ $ (resp. $\in\ ]t,0[\ $), such that
$$|f(t)-f(0)|\leq|t|\ |f'(\tau)|<\epsilon |t|\ .$$
As $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary this proves that $f'(0)=0\in X$ and at the same time that $f'$ is continuous at $0$.